# autofill only active cells down

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am having trouble coding this correctly. It keeps auto filling from the first active cell all the way to the last row. The issue is it is auto filling the hidden cells as well.

What I want to do is filter for the word "H" in a column T and in column AF, write DELETE if it contains H. Then copy this down to the rest of the filter.

```
Sub MACRO2()
'
' MACRO2 Macro
'


    LastRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
'
    Windows("WORKLIST TEMPLATE.xlsx").Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    
' FILTER COL CD H
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$AQ").AutoFilter Field:=20, Criteria1:="H"
    Range("AF1").Select

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Do Until ActiveCell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "DELETE"
    ActiveCell.AutoFill Destination:=Range(ActiveCell.Address & ":AF" & LastRow)

    Range("A1").Select
```

I need a way to code it so it is not restricted to only column AF as I need to filter and copy down on multiple columns. Any help is appreciated.

I have been searching google but I can't seem to find a solution that allows me to use the code for multiple columns. For example, I will need to filter Column S for something and then in column AF write DELETE.

Comment: `Range(ActiveCell.Address & ":AF" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) = "DELETE"`

Comment: ^ Or use `Range("AF1:AF" & LastRow)` instead of `ActiveCell.Address`.

Comment: Thanks Dave! That work perfectly. I ended up having another issue. It is the looping to find the first active cell of the column. Do you know a better way to do this? On my next filter, the first active row is 51000. The looping is taking a long time to complete.

Comment: nevermind I used Range("AF2:AF" & Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Range("A1").Select and it seem to work